# Dataframe removing "%" from strings in multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to convert multiple columns which are formatted as strings with a "%" sign to float64's. Currently I'm trying the below code but I can't figure out how to apply it to multiple columns and avoid getting an error on the date column when trying on one specific column. Any help is appreciated, header of data below.

```
web_data_bounce['TGT'] = web_data_bounce['TGT'].replace('%','',regex=True).astype('float')/100
```

[image: Data Frame]

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to set your column as index, convert, then reset:

```
web_data_bounce = (web_data_bounce
                  .set_index('Date')
                  .replace('%','',regex=True)
                  .astype('float').div(100)
                  .reset_index()
                  )
```

Another option could be to [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to only apply your transform to the numeric columns.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing the dataframe with `.loc`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_example = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019'], 
    'Num1': ['37.77%', '45.98%'],
    'Num2': ['65.99%', '18.67%']
})

df_example.loc[:, df_example.columns != 'Date'] = df_example.loc[:, df_example.columns != 'Date'].replace('%', '', regex=True).astype('float') / 100

print (df_example)
```

**Output**

```
       Date    Num1    Num2
0  1/1/2019  0.3777  0.6599
1  1/2/2019  0.4598  0.1867
```